# serverless - How to dynamically add resources generated from a javascript file and merge them with other resources?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I want to create a serverless file that deploys Cognito resources to AWS. I have a `config.yml` file that holds all the scopes that should be created in the Cognito Resource Server.

> config.yml

```yaml
- name: scope1
  description: Description of scope1
- name: scope2
  description: Description of scope2
```

What I want to accomplish is to dynamically generate one Cognito App Client for each scope we register, as well as adding these scopes to a Cognito Resource Server (in my case, the Cognito User Pool and Domain Name are already created).

To do that, I tried to make a javascript file that will load the `config.yml` file and generate two variables:

- `userPoolClientList` which holds a list of Cognito App Client resources.
- `scopeList` which represents a list of scopes that should be registered in the Cognito Resource Server.

> sls-template.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const yaml = require("js-yaml");

const scopeList = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync("config.yml"));

module.exports = {
  scopeList: function () {
    return scopeList.map(({ name, description }) => ({
      ScopeName: name,
      ScopeDescription: description,
    }));
  },

  userPoolClientList: function (serverless) {
    const { cognitoUserPoolId } = serverless.service.custom;

    const scopeResourceList = scopeList.map(({ name, description }) => ({
        [`cognitoUserPoolClient-${name}`]: {
          Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient",
          Properties: {
            AllowedOAuthScopes: [`server/${name}`],
            UserPoolId: cognitoUserPoolId,
          },
          DependsOn: "cognitoResourceServer",
        },
    }));

    return Object.assign({}, ...scopeResourceList);
  },
};
```

Now this looks like it returns exactly what I wanted (I've tested it and it works great).

My problem is rather in the implementation on the `serverless.yml` file and how to combine a fixed `Resources` and a dynamically generated one.

> serverless.yml

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    ${file(sls-template.js):userPoolClientList}
    cognitoResourceServer:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolResourceServer
      Properties:
        Identifier: server
        Name: Server
        Scopes: ${file(sls-template.js):scopeList}
        UserPoolId: ${self:custom.cognitoUserPoolId}
```

This throws an error as the syntax is not correct. However, when I try to deploy the resources individually (one time just the `cognitoResourceServer` resource, the other time the generated variable from the javascript file), everything works fine.

The problem really is on how I should combine or merge these two resources.

I've been trying a lot of different combinations to try to make it work, but it always give me an invalid template.

So I was wondering if what I try to accomplish is even possible in serverless and if so, how can I change my final `serverless.yml` file to make it work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes [resource blocks can be merged](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#multiple-configuration-files).

I believe this should do it:

```
resources:
    - Resources: ${file(sls-template.js):userPoolClientList}
    - Resources:
        cognitoResourceServer:
            Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolResourceServer
            Properties:
                Identifier: server
                Name: Server
                Scopes: ${file(sls-template.js):scopeList}
                UserPoolId: ${self:custom.cognitoUserPoolId}
```

Not 100% sure whether the dynamic block needs to generate `Resources` top-level key or whether you can hard-code it like I've shown in the example.